# Why use Process ID (PID)?

Tags: unix

I learned how you can list all the processes and their id's using either of these commands:

```
ps

tasklist
```

But so far all I have seen people use a process id is to kill the process. Given a pid, is there any other purpose?

Comment: Yes. To signal a process, to see if a process is still alive, to see what resources a process is using, to see who owns a process, to see what parent process spawned the process, and what child processes the process has spawned.

Comment: To seed a random number generator. To use in a file-naming scheme to make sure other processes won't overwrite your files. To include in log files that several processes are writing to simultaneously.

Answer (score 1):

**ps ->** Process statistics - lists currently executing processes by owner and PID (process ID) in linux.

**Uses of ps:**

- To display system processes
- To force certain actions like forcefully logging off a user, killing certain process
- The /proc directory contains subdirectories with unusual numerical names. Every one of these names maps to the process ID of a currently running process.  Within each of these subdirectories, there are a number of files that hold useful information about the corresponding process.
- Find painfully slow process
- Identify top processes by CPU and memory usage etc
- Find the hierarchy in relationship between processes
- Clubbing ps with watch command would make it a realtime reporting tool